# Unity os input detect

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am building a game which will be used on both Android and Windows OS, currently my inputs are keyboard keys which are supported on the Windows OS only.

> The question is, how do I define device/OS type in order to get related
>   inputs?

## Example

if is windows OS use `a & d` keys, if is android OS use touch `left & right` so I can have both OS support in my script in order to when i export my game it works fine is both OS.

```cs
if(windows)
{
      left = a;
      right = d;
}
else 
{
      left = leftTouch;
      right = rightTouch;
}
```

## Code

This is my current keys script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce  * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }


        if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if(rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<Manage>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [scripting platform defines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) to compile the script differently based on the target platform.

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    left = leftTouch;
    right = rightTouch;
#else
    left = a;
    right = d
#endif
```

You can do this for multiple platforms if needed using #elif

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    left = leftTouch;
    right = rightTouch;
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
    left = a;
    right = d
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
    left = macLeft;
    right = macRight;
#else
    left = defaultLeft;
    right = defaultRight;
#endif
```

Though I wouldn't do it at this deep of a level. I'd make a generic input class that you can override behavior for for different platforms, and then use these platform defines to change which derived version of that input class is used, so you're not polling for input for every platform all the time.